# Detecting If A String Is In Another String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to detect if a software version is up to date and I'm doing this by using the following code in Python 3.3:

```
if str(version) in str(buildno):
    print("Your software version is up to date. \n")
else:
    print("Your software is out of date. Updating your software. \n")
```

However, it keeps updating the software even when it is up to date. I've also tried the code variation:

```
if str(version) in str(buildno) == True:
    print("Your software version is up to date. \n")
else:
    print("Your software is out of date. Updating your software. \n")
    if os == "Windows":
        subprocess.call("windowsUpgrade.sh", shell=True)
```

which also does not work. Is the method I'm using workable or should I be taking another approach to this problem?

```
>>> print(version)
4.3.0-18107
>>> print(buildno)
('4.3.0-18107', 1)
```

Thank you for any answers provided.

Comment: You should show us what `buildno` and `version` are. This code is fine.

Comment: It simply looks like `buildno` is not in `version`. :D The first version is fine.

Comment: With a print(buildno, version) the output is "('4.3.0-18107', 1) 4.3.0-18107", so I figured I'd had them the wrong way around however the problem still persists.

Comment: this `if str(buildno) in str(version) == True:` roughly translates to `if str(buildno) in str(version) and str(version) == True:`, so don't do it.

Comment: please show us `print(buildno)` and `print(version)` separately

Comment: print(version) print(buildno) outputs 4.3.0-18107 and ('4.3.0-18107', 1). I've also added code to show how the update is performed by calling a seperate bash script.

Comment: @Metagen, please update the question with examples of `version` and `buildno`, so that everyone can easily see them.

Comment: @Metagen It seems you need `str(buildno[0]) in str(version)`

Comment: Using string containment like this can lead to trouble: `'4.3.0-1'` is in `'4.3.0-11'`, but presumably isn't up-to-date.  Depending on your version numbering strategy, you might want to make a tuple of ints to compare.

Comment: DJV that solved my problem, thank you so much :) If you want to answer my question I can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: DSM, that won't be an issue as the number for build 1 would be 00001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that there is a confusion about the datatypes used here

Tuple to String:

```
str(('4.3.0-18107', 1)) = "('4.3.0-18107', 1)"
```

Tuple not in String:

```
if "('4.3.0-18107', 1)" in '4.3.0-18107' # False
```

String in Tuple

```
if '4.3.0-18107' in "('4.3.0-18107', 1)" # True
```

String in (first index Tuple = String)

```
if '4.3.0-18107' in ('4.3.0-18107', 1)[0] # True
```

If order shouldn't matter you need to index the tuple str(('4.3.0-18107', 1)[0]) before converting to a string. What you did in your above code is you converted the tuple into a string and not the version. Pavel Anossov was therefore right that a swap should work here - at least it does it for me.

So this worked in the end (a whitespace missed out):

```
buildno=buildno[0] 
version=str(version.strip()) 
buildno=str(buildno.strip()) 
if version == buildno
```

or shorter:

```
if str(version).strip() == str(buildno[0]).strip():
if str(version).strip() in str(buildno[0]).strip():
```

Comment: Right so here's what I've done  `buildno=buildno[0]
version=str(version)
buildno=str(buildno)
print(buildno)
print(version)

if version == buildno:`  however the problem still persists despite printing the exact same output :S

Comment: Then It is something about 1.) enconding or 2.) what you are parsing isn't actually what you think it is. Try to use buildno[0].strip() and/or version.strip() to make sure you're not missing out any whitespace after your string. If everything fails reinstall python :)

Comment: See you, you are the man/woman! Problem solved, thank you so much. Also, is there any chance you could upvote this question so I can finally start upvoting answers and comments?

Comment: Glad I could help... Haha... I had a lot of problems like that when I started parsing logfiles..^^ What was it? strip or reinstall? ;)

Comment: `buildno=buildno[0]
version=str(version.strip())
buildno=str(buildno.strip())
if version == buildno:`

Answer (score 1):

Your second variation will not work. The first variation should work if you swap `buildno` and `version`:

```
buildno = '4.3.0-18107'
version = ('4.3.0-18107', 1)

if str(buildno) in str(version):
    print("Your software version is up to date. \n")
```

I assume one is a string and another one is a tuple, but they can be anything, since we only saw them printed and not how you got them.

Judging by their content, these variable names are somewhat misleading, swapped or not.

Comment: Swapping them does not work as I mentioned in the comments above. buildno is read straight from the registry using winreg and version is received from the server (this is the client side of TCP client/server) and written to a file then read and saved from that file and is indeed a tuple. I can add all the code from the client and server if you like?

Comment: The code I posted works. That means your buildno and version are different from mine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `buildno` is a tuple. You need the first item only. That is:

```
if str(buildno[0]) in str(version):
```

Or even:

```
if str(buildno[0]) == str(version):
```

as Pavel Anossov suggested in the comments.

On a side note, your second approach:

```
if str(buildno) in str(version) == True:
```

Can be roughly translated using [dis](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#dis.dis) as:

```
if str(buildno) in str(version) and str(version) == True:
```

Also, take a look at DSM's comment of your question.

> Using string containment like this can lead to trouble: '4.3.0-1' is in '4.3.0-11', but presumably isn't up-to-date. Depending on your version numbering strategy, you might want to make a tuple of ints to compare.

Comment: You might want to change it back, haha. For whatever reason `if str(buildno[0]) == str(version):` does not work

Comment: @Metagen: instead of `print(version)`, try `print(repr(version))` and `print(repr(buildno))`.  It's possible that you have trailing whitespace in `version` which is preventing the equality check from working.  (I'm on the record as thinking this is the wrong approach, though.)

Comment: @Metagen something is quite messed up with your data. As DSM states trailing whitespaces can be a reason. Also, do thing about an approach with a tuple of integers as DSM suggested.

Comment: Actually after having some lunch and coming back to this, I may have been hasty as this has not fixed my problem. Rather, it has reversed the situation so that it never updates. I'll have a quick check of the suggestions here and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Python 3, you can use the `distutils.version` comparision module described in [PEP386](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/):

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion as V

minimum_version = V(version)
current_version = V(buildno)

if current_version >= minimum_version:
    print("Your software version is up to date. \n")
else:
    print("Your software is out of date. Updating your software. \n")
```

There is also a `StrictVersion` class, but it doesn't seem to work with your version numbering.